# Ternary relationship with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in need of creating a ternary relationship with rails 3. I have found [this rails 2 resource](http://www.stonemind.net/blog/2008/03/12/exploring-ternary-associations-in-ruby-on-rails/) where the use of a model to modelate the relation is used.
Does rails 3.1 provide something better or the way to go is creating a model for the relation?

Comment: What's wrong with having multiple `has_many:through`s?

Comment: Too slow for a query that will happen a lot!

Comment: Are you using joins properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more experience on the subject with the pass of the years, I have to say that `Dave Newton` was right though not very informative. You may have several relationships in one model and then craft the queries carefully to avoid performance issues (w/includes and joins)